# Appending URL parameters to links

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I've got some pages that may or may not load with a ReturnUrl parameter, and some links that will be generated without that parameter (though I've applied a class to them).

The site uses jQuery, and I think I've found the most elegant and least breaky solution as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.my_returnlink').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+window.location.search);
    });
});
```

That is, given a page url like `http://example.com/page.aspx?ReturnUrl=blahblahblah` and the following link on the page: `<a class="my_returnlink" href="http://example.com/someotherpage.aspx">Some link</a>`, that link will end up pointing to `http://example.com/someotherpage.aspx?ReturnUrl=blahblahblah`.

Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, doing something with jQuery will perform worse than doing that same thing directly through the DOM. In this case, using the following code inside the `each` will yield better performance:

```
this.href += window.location.search;
```

Note, however, that code will create an invalid URL if there is already a query on the original `href`.

Comment: Oh, of course! That makes perfect sense, thank you.